# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Map`

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie in React and I am getting the below error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Map`.

```
  24 |        getPlacesData(bounds.sw, bounds.ne)
  25 |        .then((data) => {
  26 |            //console.log(data);
> 27 |            setPlaces(data);
  28 |        })
  29 |    }, [coordinates, bounds]);
  30 |
```

I am following the youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDa8kZLNhJ4&list=PL6QREj8te1P6wX9m5KnicnDVEucbOPsqR&index=10 specifically from timestamp 1:23:00

I have three files, App.js, Map.js, index.js (for API calls). I am trying to render the restaurants local to my coordinates (which are being displayed on the list which on the right of the map container) on the map as icons.

Here is the code for App.js:

```
const App = () => {

    const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);

    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({});
    const [bounds, setBounds] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({coords: {latitude, longitude}})=> {
            setCoordinates({lat: latitude, lng: longitude});
        })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        getPlacesData(bounds.sw, bounds.ne)
        .then((data) => {
            //console.log(data);
            setPlaces(data);
        })
    }, [coordinates, bounds]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Header />
            <Grid container spacing={3} style={{width: '100%'}}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                    <List 
                        places={places}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
                    <Map 
                        setCoordinates={setCoordinates}
                        setBounds = {setBounds}
                        coordinates={coordinates}
                        places={places}
                    />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
        
    );
}
```

Here is the code for Map.js specifically the <GoogleMapReact> component:

```
const Map = ({setCoordinates, setBounds, coordinates, places}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const isDesktop = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');

    //const coordinates = {lat: 0, lng: 0};

    return(
        <div className={classes.mapContainer}>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
                defaultCenter={coordinates}
                center={coordinates}
                defaultZoom={14}
                margin={[50, 50, 50, 50]}
                options={{}}
                onChange={(e) => {
                setCoordinates({ lat: e.center.lat, lng: e.center.lng});
                setBounds({ne: e.marginBounds.ne, sw: e.marginBounds.sw});
                }}
                onChildClick={''}
            >
                {places && places.map((place, i) => (
                    <div
                        className={classes.markerContainer}
                        lat={Number(place.latitude)}
                        lng={Number(place.longitude)}
                        key={i}
                    >
                        {
                            isDesktop ? (
                                <LocationOnOutlinedIcon 
                                    color="primary" fontSize="large"
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
                                    <Typography className={classes.typography} variant="subtitle2" gutterBottom>
                                        {place.name}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <img 
                                        className={classes.pointer}
                                        src = {place.photo ? place.photo.images.large.url : 'https://www.foodserviceandhospitality.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Restaurant-Placeholder-001.jpg'}
                                        alt={place.name}

                                    />
                                </Paper>
                            )
                        }

                    </div>
                ))}
            </GoogleMapReact>

        </div>
    );
}
```

I checked the console and I am getting the below error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')     at Object._callee$ (index.js:10:1)     at tryCatch (runtime.js:62:1)     at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:296:1)     at prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:114:1)     at step (App.js:56:1)     at App.js:56:1     at new Promise (<anonymous>)     at App.js:56:1     at getPlacesData (index.js:6:1)     at App.js:24:1     at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487:1)     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)     at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23574:1)     at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)     at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)     at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:23447:1)     at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22269:1)     at react-dom.development.js:11327:1     at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)     at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)     at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322:1)     at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309:1)     at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22438:1)     at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020:1)     at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103:1)     at ./src/index.js (index.js:5:1)     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap d5fbf406eb4fa0b6ffa5:678:1)     at fn (bootstrap d5fbf406eb4fa0b6ffa5:88:1)     at 0 (index.js:5:1)     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap d5fbf406eb4fa0b6ffa5:678:1)     at bootstrap d5fbf406eb4fa0b6ffa5:724:1     at bootstrap d5fbf406eb4fa0b6ffa5:724:1`

Here is index.js code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const URL = 'https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-in-boundary';

  
export const getPlacesData = async(sw, ne) => {
    try {
        const {data:{data}} = await axios.get(URL, {
            params: {
              bl_latitude: sw.lat,
              tr_latitude: ne.lat,
              bl_longitude: sw.lng,
              tr_longitude: ne.lng,
            },
            headers: {
              'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'API Key',
              'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
          });

        return data;
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The issue is arising when In put the following line in the <Map /> component in App.js:

```
places={places}
```

Answer (score 1):

In yout map there is no export:

add export before const Map in Map.js

export const Map = ({setCoordinates, setBounds, coordinates, places}) => {
.......
}

Comment: Hey I tried but still giving me the same error.

Although I had put this line at the end of the file:
export default Map;

Comment: Can you please put your project on Git Hub and share with me, so I can take a better look at it?

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js

Remove the 'coordinates' from the dependency array in the second argument of the useEffect.

useEffect(()=>{getPlacesData(bounds.sw,bounds.ne).then((data)=>{setPlaces(data);})},[coordinates,bounds]);

If coordinates is not being used inside the useEffect or its associated functions, removing it from the dependencies array can help avoid unnecessary re-renders triggered by changes in coordinates.

useEffect(()=>{getPlacesData(bounds.sw,bounds.ne).then((data)=>{setPlaces(data);})},[bounds]);

This will probably help to solve the issue.